# Regex oddity in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to use regular expressions to pick out file names that end with `_x.txt`. I thought that I could use the regular expression `*_x.txt` but MATLAB is being recalcitrant.

```
>> regexp( 'asdfg_x.txt', '*_x.txt' )
ans =
     []
>> regexp( 'asdfg_x.txt', '_x.txt' )
ans =
     6
```

Why does '*_x.txt' not work? I realize that it is not the best regular expression for what I am trying to accomplish, but it *should* work. I know I've done this in Linux and had it work out. I'm using Windows 7, MATLAB 2009b, presently.

Comment: Have you looked at the Matlab regex documentation?

Comment: It's not a regular expression.

Comment: I have read the MATLAB regex documentation. The expression `*_x.txt` works fine at a bash terminal. I understand how `.` and `*` work, and I understand that `.*_x\.txt` and `_x\.txt$` are better, more accurate expressions, as they are the expressions I would have used if I had written the code, but alas, I did not. I was wondering if maybe `*_x.txt` works on Linux machines, the way MATLAB graphics works differently on different processors, or if it was just an error in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a period before the asterisk to make it match:

```
regexp( 'asdfg_x.txt', '.*_x.txt' )
```

Confirmed with Octave 3.2.4

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is a [special character in regex, a quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). This character makes the preceding character/group matching 0 or more times. So this quantifier needs something to repeat, but in your expression there is nothing.

I think you mean `regexp( 'asdfg_x.txt', '.*_x.txt' )`, where [the `.` is another regex special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), matching every character except newlines. So `.*` will match a series of arbitrary characters.